# Is there any tool to index ALL bitcoind UTXO?

Tags: bitcoind, utxo

I've got a full bitcoind node with `txindex=1`.

`listunspent` command is useful only if node is in possession of a private key for address.
So, if I want to check UTXO for random address, it will not work until all of that UTXO is indexed properly.

So, are there any tools to do that simultaneously with bitcoind?

Of course there is an option to import that private key to bitcoind. But this question is larger - to get unspent for any address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that bitcoind doesn't do, but there are block explorer tools that work on top of it that will give you address-specific utxos:

- https://github.com/bitpay/insight
- https://github.com/coinbase/toshi
- https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe

Comment: Toshi is almost an answer. Is their rpc fully compatible with bitcoind rpc? That would be wonderful. I use 3rd party application that relies on bitcoind rpc formats

Comment: Nope, it is not :( And proxy can't help here - their api is limited to read operations. Question here is to find a tool to work with underlying blockchaind and fill its database with utxo index. But, I guess, it's a strange way of doing this anyway

Comment: How would these block explorers be doing this? Are they storing every transaction they receive in their own database (such as mysql)?

Comment: @inersha exactly. they do crawl through whole blockchain database (files), index it and place it somewhere else (e.g. apps' local database). My idea was if blockchain is open source and everyone knows their inner-db formats, why not to place indexed information right to utxo index of bitcoind?

Comment: I haven't tested this one and it's fairly new, but maybe another option: https://github.com/JornC/bitcoin-transaction-explorer

Comment: Why did [addrindex patch](https://github.com/btcdrak/bitcoin/releases) not make your list? Also toshi is 404 now.

Comment: Toshi appears to be... gone?

Answer (score 0):

ElectrumX is open source software that you can install on your own node (if you're running one) that will index your UTXOs for any address.

https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx

You'd use the `blockchain.address.listunspent` RPC command along with the address you're interested about