# NodeJS code to deobfuscate chainstate data

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, address, block

I am currently working on a Blockchain trading platform for a company and I want to have all the unspent output saved to a local database by reading the contents of chainstate folder but I couldn't deobfuscate the `value` field of the records.

Please is there any sample code in NodeJS for that or can anybody please help?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/48096/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/83536/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/53865/5406. Also potentially relevant: https://github.com/theStack/utxo_dump_tools